# How to shuffle data in a column

Tags: python

I am trying to shuffle data in a file with four columns as follows:

```
A  1  2  3 

B  0  5  6

C  2  4  7

D  7  8  9

E  10 4  8
```

I only want to shuffle the first column. So, am expecting something like this

```
E  1  2  3 

D  0  5  6

C  2  4  7

A  7  8  9

B  10 4  8
```

Does anyone have any idea how to do this? I have tried something like this

```py
with open("file.txt", "rb") as source:
    lines = [line for line in source]

import random
random_choice = random.sample(lines, 5)

with open("newfile.txt", "wb") as sink:
    sink.write("\n".join(random_choice))

with open('newfile.txt', 'r') as fd:
    for l in fd:
        if l != '\n':
            print(l.strip())
```

But observed that all the other columns also changes.

Answer (score 1):

I arranged your code and comment it for explanations :

```py
import random

# open file.txt read-only
with open("file.txt", "r") as source:
    # get data without double spaces and line feeds
    lines = [line.replace("  ", " ").strip() for line in source]

data = [li.split(" ") for li in lines]
# get the first column data
keys = [dat[0] for dat in data]
# get the other column values
values = [dat[1:] for dat in data]
# mix first column
random_keys = random.sample(keys, 5)
# re-assemble
new_list = [[random_keys[i]] + val for i, val in enumerate(values)]
new_lines = [" ".join(nl) for nl in new_list]

# write newfile.txt
with open("newfile.txt", "w") as destination:
    [destination.write(nl + "\n") for nl in new_lines]
```